# Q.all.then doesn't wait for completion

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have a service in separate JS file, this service is like OOP class that holds 'methods' to load necessary data from the web.

I want call those 'methods' and get the data in my main JS file, actually I want to load data of three types and force JS flow to wait untill that data is retrieved, here's my code:

**services.js**

```
// My 'Class' to load data from the web server
myApp.factory("LoadData", ["_gl", function (_gl) {
    return {        
        GetUsers: function ($http) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/dgis/ps/select.php',
                data: { "action": "GetUsers" }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // Save the response JSON object to my global objects
                _gl.myUsers = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("GetUsersError:" + response);
            });
        },
        GetObGroups: function ($http) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/dgis/ps/select.php',
                data: { "action": "GetObGroups" }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // Save the response JSON object to my global objects
                // This code fills array because it iterates through it

                angular.forEach(response.data, function (value, key) {
                    _gl.myObGroups.push(value)
                });
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("GetObGroups:" + response);
            });
        },
        GetObjects: function ($http) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/dgis/ps/select.php',
                data: { "action": "GetObjects" }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                _gl.myObjects = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("GetObjectsError:" + response);
            });
        }
    }
}]);

// My global variables
myApp.factory('_gl', function () {
    return {
        myUsers: [],
        myOrganisations: [],
        myObGroups: [],
        myObjects: []
    }
});
```

**script.js**

```
 Q.all([LoadData.GetUsers($http), LoadData.GetObGroups($http),  LoadData.GetObjects($http)]).then(function () {
          console.log(_gl.myUsers);
          console.log(_gl.myObGroups);
          console.log(_gl.myObjects);     
      });
```

The problem is, the `Q.all` won't wait till all http request will get the data, it evaluates calls in `then` before it happens. Sure, I could use some timer and just wait for a second, but I want more proper way to do that, please share with your knowledge.

And one more thing, if I use `forEach` in `then` of my get methods then arrays filling all right, but other arrays are empty and I want to know why it happens.

Thank you.

Comment: Make [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *return* the promises in `GetUsers`, `GetObGroups` and `GetObjects`, otherwise `Q.all` can't do its job.

Therefore, e.g.:

```
GetUsers: function ($http) {
        return $http({
        ....
```

should do the trick.

Comment: also would be more sensible to inject `$http` in factory instead of passing as argument for each method. And no need to `return response.promise` in each `then`

Comment: @charlietfl true, and perhaps use `.spread` instead of `.all` and accessing the `_gl` variable; I was just trying to help fixing the existing issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, the response.promise I only wrote to check if anything will change but it didn't till now))